# Node js encryption

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption

I am trying to write encrypted content to file , following [this](http://lollyrock.com/articles/nodejs-encryption/)

For first call to log() it works fine,file has `0c8bd89c2e` it decrypts "hello", but after second call to `log` it appends data to file `0c8bd89c2e0c8bd89c2e` but decrypts it like `hello���`

What am i doing wrong here? and how to correct this ?

```
var fs = require('fs');
var crypto = require('crypto'),
    algorithm = 'aes-256-ctr',
    password = 'd6F3Efeq';

function encrypt(text){
  var cipher = crypto.createCipher(algorithm,password)
  var crypted = cipher.update(text,'utf8','hex')
  crypted += cipher.final('hex');
  return crypted;
}

function decrypt(text){
  var decipher = crypto.createDecipher(algorithm,password)
  var dec = decipher.update(text,'hex','utf8')
  dec += decipher.final('utf8');
  return dec;
}


var tmp = {
    log : function(req,res){
        // var data = body.UserName+" "+body.Domain+" "+body.Password+"  ";
        var data = "hello";
        fs.appendFile("./objects/tmp.dat",encrypt(data), function(err) {
            if (err)
                console.error(err);
            else{
                console.log("done");
            }
            res.send();
        });


    },
    test: function(req,res){
        var data = fs.readFileSync("./objects/tmp.dat",{encoding:'utf8'});

        res.send(decrypt(data));
    }
}

module.exports = tmp;
```

Comment: What is the "first time" and the "second time"?

Comment: @zerkms edited question

Comment: So why do you think that you can concatenate 2 encrypted texts and decrypt them back as a single thing? What cryptography property makes you thinking it is a legal operation?

Comment: @zerkms ya i kinda figured what i am doing wrong , but whats the work around ? i want to write encrypted text to file which vl come in parts and read them out in a single operation

Comment: You cannot concatenate independent encrypted strings and decrypt them as a whole. You cannot work it around, since it is not a designed property of the selected encryption algorithm. What you can do instead - is read them and decrypt in chunks. So just write them on different lines (or using any other separator) and decrypt line by line, separately.

Comment: Using `crypto.createCipher(algorithm,password)` multiple times with CTR mode and with the same password is *incredibly* insecure. If you're encrypting something many times with CTR, you need to use a different nonce (IV), but `crypto.createCipher` will derive the same IV for the same password. If you're not using different IV's you'll create a many-time pad which is fully deducible when the attacker knows a little bit about the form of the plaintext.

Comment: @zerkms instead i started keeping it in json and i keep json key val encrypted, thanks for helping out though